# Navigation problem in Popup and how to use setLocationRelativeto()

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a `JButton` named `Graphics`:

[image]

When I press it, a new popup menu appears and the user selects Screen Resolution:

[image]

I have added custom images to menu items, I am unable to navigate to any of the menu items using arrow keys.

The second problem is that the popup menu does not stick within the frame, please let me know how to make it to stick within `JFrame` or graphics button.

I have tried KeyListener But that didn't work.

In the following code, I have created a `JPopupMenu` and initialized it and in the `KeyListener` function, I have tried to solve the problem of navigating but it didn't work.

```
popgraphics=new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem p1920=new JMenuItem();
JMenuItem p1536=new JMenuItem();
JMenuItem p1280=new JMenuItem();
p1920.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icons\\1920p.png")));
p1536.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icons\\1536p.png")));
p1280.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icons\\1280p.png")));
p1920.setBorder(b1);
// p1920.setText("1920x1080 Pixels");
// p1536.setText("1536x1440 Pixels");
// p1280.setText("1280x720 Pixels");

p1920.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",0,14));
p1536.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",0,14));
p1280.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",0,14));

p1920.setOpaque(false);
p1536.setOpaque(false);
p1536.setOpaque(false);

// popgraphics.setSelected(null);
// popgraphics.setSelectionModel(SingleSelectionModel);
popgraphics.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar()==(char)38)
        {
            if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(2);
            }
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar()==(char)40)
        {
            if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(2);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyChar()==(char)38)
        {
            if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(2);
            }
        }
        if(e.getKeyChar()==(char)40)
        {
            if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==1)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(2);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==2)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(3);
            }
            else if(popgraphics.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()==3)
            {
                popgraphics.getSelectionModel().setSelectedIndex(1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});

popgraphics.add(p1280);
popgraphics.add(p1536);
popgraphics.add(p1920);
Point p=graghics.getLocation();
popgraphics.setLocation(p);
popgraphics.setBackground(new Color(20,20,20));
popgraphics.setOpaque(false);
```

Let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Abra I have Edited,  I can again explain to you that, i have 2 problems , First is of navigate  to menu items after adding icons as menuitems and second is that i am unable to make Jpopup menu within the Jframe, like when i minimize or move frame , popup menu show move with frame.

Comment: Abra I am new to Stackoverflow , I am not able to understand what  things you asking me to.

Comment: I have read the link, and kind of tried to present my problem, please do help if you got my problem.

Comment: That KeyListener should be removed.  No one should be explicitly managing keyboard navigation of a JPopupMenu.  One thing that is absent from your code is the actual showing of the JPopupMenu.  The only correct way to display a JPopupMenu is with its `show` method (or by passing it to setComponentPopupMenu so it can be shown automatically).  If you are explicitly adding your JPopupMenu to a parent, that would explain your difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple program that displays a `JButton` with a large icon. A `JPopupMenu` is connected to the `JButton`. The `JPopupMenu` contains two `JMenuItem` where each one has its own, separate icon. Run the program. Place the mouse pointer over the `JButton`. Bring up the `JPopupMenu`. (On my Windows 10 machine, I click the right mouse button display the `JPopupMenu`.) Then hit the down arrow key on the keyboard.

```java
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;

public class PopupTst {

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Icon ico = new ImageIcon("first icon"); // replace with actual path to icon.
        JButton button = new JButton(ico);

        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        Icon ico2 = new ImageIcon("second icon"); // replace with actual path to icon.
        JMenuItem one = new JMenuItem(ico2);
        popup.add(one);
        Icon ico3 = new ImageIcon("third icon"); // replace with actual path to icon.
        JMenuItem two = new JMenuItem(ico3);
        popup.add(two);

        button.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PopupTst instance = new PopupTst();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```